# Rudin's proof dominated convergence theorem; failing to spot condition

Tags: real-analysis, integration

After working with the theorem for a year, I suddenly realize I have not understood Rudin's proof of the dominated convergence theorem in "Real and Complex Analysis", theorem 1.34.

I find that if I replace his function $f$ which is the limit of the sequence $f_n$, by an arbitrary function $h$ which is $L^1$, I can still do the same proof, which is absurd of course. I know i am doing something stupid, but where is it?:

There is a sequence $(f_n)$ of measurable functions, and a $g$ in $L^1$, such that $| f_n(x)| \leq g(x)$ for all $n$ and $x$. I do not use the limit of $f_n$, but any different measurable function $h$, with $|h(x)|\leq g(x)$ for all $x$. (There must be one, eg $f_0$ if ($f_n$) is not constant)
Then I go through the proof with this $h$:

$h$ is in $L^1$.
$|f_n - h| \leq 2g$
Apply Fatou's lemma to $2g - |f_n - h|$ , which yields
$\int 2g\ dm \leq \liminf \int (2g - |f_n - h|)\ dm$
$= \int 2g\ dm + \liminf (- \int |f_n -h |\ dm )$
$=\int 2g\ dm -  \limsup \int |f_n - h|\ dm$

since $\int 2g $ is finite, the $\limsup \int |f_n-h| \leq 0$
which (almost) yields the result.

The result is absurd for an arbitrary $h$, I guess the fact that $\lim |f_n - f| = 0$, in case $h=f=\lim f_n$, should be used, and that is missing here, but in which line?

Where does my mind go (terribly) wrong here ?

I do have a proof from school, and the one from Kolmogorov's introductory analysis, my question is about this proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $h$ is chosen arbitrarily with the only constraint being $\lvert h\rvert\leq g$, then Fatou’s lemma would yield $$\int \liminf (2g-\lvert f_n - h\rvert) \leq \liminf\int (2g - \lvert f_n - h\rvert).$$
However, we cannot say that the integrand on the left is equal to $2g$, unless we choose $h = \lim f_n$. That’s where your proof goes wrong.

Comment: That was embarrassing, i just looked at the right hand side, and lost hours. Thanks.

Comment: @GuyMatoFailo It’s an easy thing to overlook because Rudin’s proof begins with $2g$ on the left-hand side without mentioning that this is because $2g = \liminf(2g - \lvert f_n - f\rvert)$. It’s bit terse, and the only advantage is that the proof is shorter by one line.